# How to identify which data set is used by a report in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

How to identify the dataset of a report is based on. We have been using a powerbi work space since long time. There are multiple data sets and reports were added over the time. We lost track on what reports are using which data sets, and like to clean up if there are any used datasets.

Thanks
Jyothi

Comment: after posting this question, did few more clicks and i see that there is "View Related" on right side top and able to see the data set information.

Comment: Hi Jyothi, post your comment as an answer and mark it so that its useful for other people.

Answer (score 3):

"View Related" Option on right side top corner will provide the data set information.